# Не могу отобразить веб-страницу из контейнера Docker в браузере

Tags: laravel, docker, curl

Есть готовый проект laravel, я создаю контейнер для него, все проходит успешно, после его запуска не могу отобразить страницу, переходя по ссылке. Ниже информация о контейнере.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                                            
e4aa0b1e5229   rep2      "docker-php-entrypoi…"   8 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds  
PORTS
 0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp
```

При использовании CURL по адресу localhost:8000 или 0.0.0.0:8000 выдает ошибку:

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Соединение разорвано другой стороной

Comment: Зачем делать запрос на порт 8000 когда он внутренний, и соответствует 80 внешнему? (8000->80)

Comment: Я и описал ситуацию, потому что не понимаю, что делаю не так, если вы поняли в чем проблема, не могли бы подробнее объяяснить?

Comment: Запрос вы делаете на правильный порт, т.к. 80 - внутри контейнера, а 8000 - снаружи. А проблема может быть вызвана тем, что у вас `laravel` слушает не на том адресе/порту внутри контейнера, или чем-то ещё