# Artisan показывает только стартовую страницу моего laravel проекта

Tags: php, laravel, http, docker, artisan

Artisan показывает только стартовую страницу моего laravel проекта, при попытке перейти на следующую страницу возникает ошибка 500. Проект лежит в контейнере Docker, и artisan запускается, соответственно там же, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: логи смотрите. `$ docker logs контейнер`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу отобразить веб-страницу из контейнера Docker в браузере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328388/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-docker-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)